# Testing IPV6 code on Android

Tags: android, networking, ipv6

We would like to set up an IPV6 dev environment for testing our IPV6 network code on Android. Its just that it doesn't seem possible for an Android handset to connect to an IPV6 WiFi network. There is no option even on a Samsung S7 to enter a static IPV6 address. So how can we devs test this. We are using a MAC to set up a IPV6 only WiFi network for testing.

Comment: My Android 5.1.1+ devices connect perfectly to a Mac set up with a [NAT64 test network as specified by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16).

Comment: Well I tried on a Nexus 4 Version 5.1.1. When I connect to the NAT64 network from my MAC its just stuck at Obtaining IP address. Can you tell me any settings I need to change to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: Can you say what interface the Android handset is supposed to connect to the MAC NAT64 network Simply can't see how to do this over WiFi

Comment: The interface name is `wlan0` on my old Razr HD running CM 12.1 and also `wlan0` on my Nexus 6 running 7.0. Works perfectly. Just connect to the network.

Answer (score 1):

Use DHCPv6.  Its supported as of Android 5.1.1

Edit:  I've seen some sources claim dhcpv6 works, but it seems like am oem addition if so.  So not universal, but is worth trying.  I've also seen claims that SLAAC works

Comment: As far as I am aware DHCPv6 is not supported. Google's position is still not to support this. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32621

Comment: How to set up SLAAC with Android

Comment: SLAAC means that the router sends out router advertisements that have the flag set to allow the client to choose its own IPv6 address based on the /64 advertised in the router advertisement.

Comment: I don't get DHCPv6 addresses on 5.1.1, or even on 7.0. I do get SLAAC and privacy addresses though, on both of these.